# how to extract database content in a javascript file

Tags: javascript

I am using devexpress filter table with jQuery in a spring project , the grid contains the " index.html file " , " index.js" file which contains the table columns and titles , and "data.js" files which contains the informations of the table, i putted the js files in the "static" folder in spring project and the html file in the "template" file everything works correctly , now i want to change the "data.js" content with my sql server database informations, how can i do it please ?

`data.js` content:

```
var orders = [
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "OrderNumber": 35703,
    "OrderDate": "2017/04/10",
    "DeliveryDate": "2017/04/13 9:00",
    "SaleAmount": 11800,
    "Terms": "15 Days",
    "CustomerStoreCity": "Los Angeles, CA",
    "Employee": "Harv Mudd"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code from `data.js` is executed in the browser, meaning it won't have access to the db server.

What you need to do is **create an API endpoint** in your spring project. This API endpoint will access your database. In your `data.js` file you'll have to make an ajax call to the above API endpoint to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

i have created an api endpoint with this code : `import java.util.List;

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private tbl_sped_tratteDAO tbl_sped_trattedao; 

@RequestMapping(value = "/grid", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSpeds(Model model) { 
    List<tbl_sped_tratte> list = tbl_sped_trattedao.getSpedInfos(); 
    
    model.addAttribute("spedInfos", list); 
    
    return "tableau";
}
```

}
`

now when i try to make an ajax call i dont know how to call a list attribute , all tutorials i have read the ajax function have called 1 attribute called id or name , i dont know how to call a list of attributes.